# How to combine different data types java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop

I have three different entities (Deposit,Withdraw and Transfer). Deposit and Withdraw have the same schema structure(so no need of me showing the entity) but transfer is slightly different. I have a requirement to fetch all user transactions and sort them without the front-end doing extra logic. How do i join them and sort since they are of different structure?

Below are my entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false,updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false,updatable = false)
    private Long sourceAccount;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false,name = "transaction_detail_id")
    private TransactionDetail transactionDetail;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false,updatable = false)
    private Date transactionDate;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false,updatable = false)
    private Time time;

}

@Entity
public class Deposit extends Transaction {

    @Column(nullable = false,updatable = false)
    @Positive
    private BigDecimal amount;
}

@Entity
public class Deposit extends Transaction {

    @Column(nullable = false,updatable = false)
    @Positive
    private BigDecimal amount;
}

@Entity
public class Transfer extends Transaction{


    @Column(nullable = false,updatable = false,name = "desc_acct")
    private Long recipientAccount;
    @Column(nullable = false,updatable = false)
    private BigDecimal amount;



}

@Entity
public class TransactionDetail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long transactionId;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TransactionStatus transactionStatus;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TransactionType transactionType;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false,updatable = false)
    private Date transactionDate;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false,updatable = false)
    private Time time;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: I guess you can write a custom comparator that compare these objects by `Date` then by `Time`. The problem is that your `Entity` classes cannot implement an interface. So, your "list" will have to accept generic "objects" and you will have to use `instanceof` to discriminate against everything else except for these entities. Sounds like a lot of work. Good luck!

Comment: Come to think about it, you can create three lists (one for each type) that are already sorted. Then, you will need to merge these lists by `Date` and `Time`. This is probably your best bet.

Comment: from my perspective all those entities could be backed up by a single table in DB (in that case transfers must be represented by two rows - in and out)

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov could you expatiate better especially the in and out part. I already have a relationship but is unidirectional .

Comment: @hfontanez i tried using java stream concat api but it kept missing the getter for  recipientAccount field in the transfer entity.

Comment: @ferrocene all your entities actually represent just different types of account-related transactions, so base entity type should be Transaction, next you need add a field which describes transaction type and, optionally, use that field as discriminator (if you want to manage different classes for different transaction types). Two DB records for transfers are required to avoid using `OR` or `UNION when querying transactions - both of them are very inconvenient and have performance impact.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I have updated my question. That is how my entity looked like but the issue is that i have no bidirectional mapping at transaction detail entity or there is problem with my schema model?

Comment: MappedSuperClass just tells HBN to use in as a source of information about attributes. In your case that should be full-functional entity, it that case you will able to query it, sort, filter, etc.

Comment: @ferrocene Since they are all extending the same super-class, Compare them as `Transaction` and then sort by `Transaction.date` then by `Transaction.time`. I don't see why that would not work.

Comment: "_i tried using java stream concat api but it kept missing the getter..._" it would help tremendously if you add that code to your question. Not only it is relevant to the question, it is Stack Overflow "policy", and it will help us help you figure out why your attempt didn't work and/or propose solution that might work.

Comment: @hfontanez thanks i have compared them and it worked

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Thanks i used the discriminator and it worked fine thanks but one more thing is there a way to avoid joins. should i merge  the transactional detail entity into the transaction entity?

Comment: @ferrocene have you read this: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-lazy-loading-one-to-one/ ? My own preference is to not use o2o associations

Comment: @ferrocene Glad to hear that it worked. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model like DTO (Data Transfer Object), then you get/set value for DTO and sort them before transfer it to front-end.

Another solution is using [Bazaarvoice Jolt](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bazaarvoice.jolt) instead of get/set manually

Comment: Word of advice: This is more of a comment than an answer. Don't be surprised if people start downvoting it. I don't typically do this. You can see this comment was posted before any downvotes. I just want to warn you. If you can, improve your answer by posting an example of what you are suggesting.  If you see my posted comment on the question, there's a reason why I didn't post it as an answer.